# Docker build image failed? Failed to compute cache key: "/app" not found: not found

Tags: python, macos, docker, dockerfile

Error :

```sh
failed to compute cache key: "/app" not found: not found
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

Error in `COPY ./app app`

Operating System: MacOS

Is someone faced this problem ?

[image: project structure]

Comment: On your host system, do you have an `app` subdirectory of your top-level directory (that has the `requirements.txt` file)?

Comment: added project structure, its really simple

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The APP folder does not exist in your project

You are trying to add an APP folder that does not exist into your docker container and it is complaining because there is no APP folder to add into the container

In the line

```
COPY ./APP /APP
```

The `./APP` must reflect a folder that is in your project

Comment: the same problem

Comment: Is the app folder in the same folder as the Dockerfile?

Comment: added project structure

Comment: @tarp20 I don't see any app folder in that screenshot. Is there any folder or file actually called app?

Comment: there is no folder / file called app

Comment: Well there is your error, you are trying to add a folder called APP in your current directory into the docker container and it does not exist

Comment: I've got a similar issue and I do have the folder in the project.  I can even nano it from a full path.

Comment: Also check you've not added it to the `.dockerignore` file.

Comment: @zessx Thanks! Several days I've been struggling with it and here is you, the savior that we all needed.

Comment: In my case, This is work well, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[maybe IDE 's fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acrcA.png)
check you've not added it to .dockerignore file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Another reason may be the files/folder you are trying to copy are **not in the docker context**. Make sure that if Dockerfile is present inside some subdirectory of parent directory e.g. **parent-dir/child-dir/Dockerfile** , run the docker build command from parent directory instead  as below

```
docker build -f parent-dir/child-dir/Dockerfile -t image .
```

Comment: This was the issue for me as well, when manually building a vscode devcontainer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, if you clone a repository and it has a Dockerfile in it, you can solve the issue by running this command `docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t image .` inside the repository working dir. It directs the docker container to work with the Docker file in your repository, and it can locate the `requirements.txt` file in it.